# sdl2 flickering unless I don't use createrenderer

Tags: c, sdl-2, renderer

I have a somewhat basic rendering loop which blits a scaled image to the screen as fast as I can process the event loop.  I created a minimal example that recreates the flickering on [pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/y5eJjQbx).

If I don't use "SDL_CreateRenderer", and instead leave renderer to NULL, it works.  I just can't clear the screen first.  If I set the renderer, I get this crazy fast flickering.

```
// if I comment this out in my init_sdl(), no flickering...
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
assert(renderer != NULL);
```

my draw function happens at the end of the event loop:

```
void draw()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 128, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
 
    SDL_Rect dstrect = {
        .x = 50,
        .y = 50,
        .h = 100,
        .w = 100,
    };
    SDL_BlitScaled(img, NULL, screen, &dstrect);
 
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

I've seen this [potential duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236672/flickering-while-drawing-multiple-sdl-texture-using-sdl2), but the problem was that they had their RenderPresent in the wrong place. You can see I'm calling `SDL_RenderPresent` at the end of all drawing operations, which was my takeaway from that.  It is still happening.

I'm using msys2 (mingw_x64), gcc, windows 10, SDL2.

Comment: The [`SDL_GetWindowSurface()` docs](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.0.18/include/SDL_video.h#L1224) specifically say not to combine it with the rendering API.

Comment: Great find.  I will try to remove that as soon as I get home from work and see if that's what the problem is.